# Gradle custom plugin as a standalone project

Tags: gradle

I have custom gradle plugin as a standalone project. I would like to use it in other project.

Suppose that plugin is not yet build. Is there any way how can I compile my plugin (in my other project) and add it on classpath to buildScript block all in one build.gradle of my other project ?

I am new to gradle so sorry if this is dumb question.